# A scientific term for 'beginning of sampling in a signal'

Tags: american-english, science

I have a Signal of 3 seconds. At different times I start sampling(extract samples) . I need a word  that refers to the beginning of each sampling in the signal. I thought of starting point but I am looking for a more accurate term, that sounds more scientific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

***[Sample start](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/949465?tstart=0)***

You can see the phrase being used in the context you've mentioned in a discussion on apple.com, they are talking about music, but whatever you are sampling, I am sure the terminology applies equally as well:

> The loop needs to start somewhere after the sample start, and the loop
>   needs to end before the sample end.

or to be less idiomatic, you might use:

***Sample start point***

As used in [this video](https://www.lynda.com/Ableton-Live-tutorials/Smoothing-sample-start-end-points-Simpler/120600/132072-4.html), on lynda.com:

> ...sample start and end points...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the term **epoch**.

Epoch specifically refers to time points or "windows" and is a term commonly used in brain imaging studies. For example, here is how epoch is used to describe the design of one [study](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1118/1.1354627/full):

> Each exercise run consisted of a 30-s pre-exercise epoch, ten 20-s stimulation epochs separated by ten 20-s control epochs, and a 50-s after-exercise epoch.

For your situation I wouldn't be able to comment without knowing more about what it is you are intending to do, but epoch could be used like so:

> The signal was of 3 seconds duration, and sampled into epochs, each 500 ms in length.